# Optimised Math functions for React Native

Tags: react-native

The execution time of this function is in milliseconds and sometimes in even seconds. It goes upto 3 seconds on my watch. I was wondering for optimised library to address this issue.

```
export function calculate_angle(v1, v0, v2){
    var x1 = v1[0] - v0[0];
    var x2 = v2[0] - v0[0];
    var y1 = v1[1] - v0[1];
    var y2 = v2[1] - v0[1];
    var dot_product = x1*x2 + y1*y2;
    var cross_product = Math.sqrt((x1*x1+ y1*y1) * (x2*x2 + y2*y2));
    return Math.acos(dot_product/cross_product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do some heavy calculations client side. If you have a server your application communicates with I would recommend sending those calculations to the server.

React Native is not optimised to carry out such compute heavy tasks. If you can't run those calculations on a server I would look to try and get "closer to the metal", i.e. create a native module that you can run those queries in, and only use React Native for the UI.

Or if it's an option you could consider Flutter. Flutter is compiled into the native ARM code for both Android and iOS, unlike React Native which runs a lot of it's "logic" in the Javascript engine.

Comment: What about the request and response time for external server ?

Native module for such queries would be great. If its okay for you, I wouldn't mind helping as much as I can.